# CSS3: Change Page Background Image if Image is Hovered

Tags: css, background-image, css-transitions

I am trying to change the page's background image depending on the image being hovered.

This is the layout of the page:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <img id="img1" src="1.jpg" />
    <img id="img2" src="2.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#img1:hover #main
{
    background: url('images/1.jpg'); /* not working */
}

#img2:hover #main
{
    background: url('images/2.jpg'); /* not working */
}
```

'#main' is the ID I set for the  tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using <= IE7?

Comment: @Aiias: I am currently using Google Chrome.

Comment: Is `#main` a parent element of `#img1` or `#img2`? It looks that way in the picture. `<div id="main"><img id="img1" /><img id="img2 /></div>` ?

Comment: Yes. #main is a parent element of the two.

Comment: Then this current layout is not doable via a CSS selector. The hierarchy must follow the style definition. So in this case, `#main` would have to be a child element of `#img1` for the selector to stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need change the background-image of #main div you should use CSS and jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Soldier/cyAXv/1/

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <h1>Hi!</h1>
    <img id="img1" src="img1"/>
    <img id="img2" src="img2"/>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$('#img1').hover(function() {
    $('#main').css("background","url('background1')");
})

$('#img2').hover(function() {
    $('#main').css("background","url('background2')");
})
```

Comment: Tried testing your syntax: http://pastie.org/7190658. It's not yet working. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sure, you forget put http: in jquery path, put $(document).ready(function() .. http://pastie.org/7190685

Answer (score 1):

You can't traverse backwards in CSS selectors. That is to say, you can't apply a style to an ancestor/parent based on the state of a child/descendant.

You will need to use JavaScript unfortunately. You can use classes and define the styles in CSS though to make it less lame. Something like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/sveN8/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="img1"></div>
    <div id="img2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main.img1 {
    background: url('https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
}
#main.img2 {
    background: url('https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
}
#img1,
#img2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F00;
    margin:10px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var main = document.getElementById('main'),
    img1 = document.getElementById('img1'),
    img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

img1.onmouseover = function () {
    main.className = 'img1';
};
img2.onmouseover = function () {
    main.className = 'img2';
};
img1.onmouseout = function () {
    main.className = '';
};
img2.onmouseout = function () {
    main.className = '';
};
```

Comment: Forking makes an identical copy, are you sure you didn't change the code?